# Why a jax-rs service with return type Iterable<MyClass> works while Collection<MyClass> doesn't?

Tags: java, collections, jersey, jax-rs, iterable

Say I have a simple class Person with name and last name as properties. Also suppose I have a simple rest service with get endpoints that return a list of people.

```
public class Person {
    // name and last name properties plus getters and setters
}

// Service
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("test")
public class SimpleRestService {
    //Suppose people is initialized and contains actual people
    private ArrayList<Person> people;

    @GET
    @PATH("/people/iterable")
    public Iterable<Person> getPeople(){
        //This one works
        return people;
    }

    @GET
    @PATH("/people/collection")
    public Collection<Person> getPeople(){
        //This one fails. HTTP 500. Nothing on server.log ...
        return people;
    }
}
```

The fisrt endpoin *test/people/iterable* will work fine while *test/people/collection* will fail with HTTP 500. Does any one have a clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

Jersey has a registry relating the MIME type in the `@Produces` with the Java type the method is declared to return and the handler that processes the object to produce the payload of the response.  It has a handler that converts `Iterable` and `List` to a JSON `Array`.  It also has a handler that converts `Map` to a JSON `Object`.  The problem with the Java interface `Collection` is that there is no indication as to whether it should be represented as a sequential collection (JSON `Array`) or an unordered collection of named items (JSON `Object`).  Thus there is no handler registered by default for converting `Collection` to `application/json`.  This is what the message in the exception logged on your application server indicates.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about this. It has to do more with generics and [TypeEreasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). I did tests, creating a Person class and the services above, but I was able to return both Iterable or Collection indifferently. Then I added some generics and it stopped working for both, Iterable and Collection. I tried to reproduce the exact same scenario when I was able to return an Iterable and not a Collection, but unfortunately I  couldn't do so. Then... I don't know whether this is still a valid question or not since I cannot replicate it